# Getting user token on Google Plus

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am trying to integrate with Google plus with Parse, where users would signin using Google plus, and their credentials would get stored at Parse.

To achieve this, I have added the following code:

```
private void onGoogleButtonClicked() {
        ParseUser.becomeInBackground("session-token-here", new LogInCallback() {
                  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                          // The current user is now set to user.
                        } else {
                          // The token could not be validated.
                        }
                      }
                    });

            }
        });
```

Now my issue remains in finding the session token derived from Google Plus. I have begin my journey with the following code:

```
 final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                         mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
```

Now I need to do something with context, mPlusCLient, and scope. Any help will be appreciated as I have been struggling with this issue for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an `Asynctask` for retrieving the token as you don't want this process to stutter the ui. Get the `account name` of the user signed in and call the `Asynctask` to get the token. Here is a sample code :

```
 private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Token : " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

You could call the `Asynctask` in the following manner :

```
String mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
new RetrieveTokenTask().execute(mAccountName);
```